# Determine if entity has a temporary id

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, anonymous-types

I have a generic save method that adds a `TModel` to a `TDbSet` and then does a `SaveChanges()`.

To determine if this was an "add" or an "update" I was simply setting the entity state based on whether or not `Id == 0`, which was working as desired when the ids were all ints.

I then went through and modified the ids so they could be more generic as well, essentially allowing primary keys in my system to be either ints or guids as desired.

I haven't been able to figure out a solid test for determining if this is a save or modify in this scenario. I get the following error:

> The property 'MyModel.Id' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Modified'. Either set a permanent value explicitly, or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.'

Which indicates that my condition is failing.

```
public virtual TModel Save(TModel data)
{
    _dynamic.Add(data);
    _context.Entry(data).State =
        data.Id == null || (data?.Id.Equals(0) ?? true)
            ? EntityState.Added 
            : EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return data;
}
```

Where Id is `IEquatable<TKey>`, in my particular scenario a `long`.

VS2022 is making it even more confusing by providing a value of `0` for `data.Id` in a watch, but then also providing a `Expression has been evaluated and has no value` in the tooltip when hovering over `data?.Id`.

I was hoping there was a clear-cut way to determine if the primary key for an entity was a "temporary value". I would think there must be, as this error message would have to know, but I haven't been able to unearth it. So far I can only find instances of people trying to find a way to set that value manually.

Comment: If you want to be able to compare to the default value for the type of the `Id` property then you have to be able to get that default value, which would require that type to be a generic type parameter for the class you're in. You could then use `default(T)` where you're currently using `0`.

Comment: Absolutely a "duh" moment here for me. That should be an answer, not just a comment

Comment: I posted a comment because I think an answer should have more detail. I'm happy for you to post an answer once you have implemented the suggestion and that was my intention.